# How to not show graphs until plt.show() in jupyter notebook or jupyter_lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter and jupyter lab to analyze data.

In case of showing graph, I want to show all of graph in the last cell.

But jupyter and jupyter lab show graph right after setting plot code like

```
plt.scatter(regdata[0],regdata[1])
```

What I want to do is setting plots in above different cells and showing in the last cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent plot from showing in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717877/prevent-plot-from-showing-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 5):

This is a duplicate of [how to reuse plot in a next jupyter cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537457/how-to-reuse-plot-in-next-jupyter-cell).

To summarise, you can just call the figure again in a later cell.

**First cell**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.close() # close figure to stop it showing in this cell.
```

To display this figure in a later cell you can just call the figure again:

**Second cell**

```
fig
```

This will display the figure