# Seaborn to create two lineplots from different dataframes, reusing these plots in several chunks, and then combining these plots in another chunk

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537457/how-to-reuse-plot-in-next-jupyter-cell), I discovered how to reuse a plot.

This is the first plot

```
plot_depression, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax=sns.lineplot(x="time", 
            y="value", 
            hue = "Group",
            ci=90, err_style='bars',
            data=df_long)
ax.set(xlabel = "Time", ylabel = "Result")
ax.set_title('Trajectory of depression during the pandemic', size=20)
```

This is the second plot

```
plot_anxiety, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax=sns.lineplot(x="time", 
            y="value", 
            hue = "Group",
            ci=90, err_style='bars',
            data=df_long2)
ax.set(xlabel = "Time", ylabel = "Result")
ax.set_title('Trajectory of anxiety during the pandemic', size=20)
```

In any chunk, I can reuse these plots by calling `plot_depression` or `plot_anxiety`.
However, when I try to combine these two plots using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67051374/5893454), the result is two empty plots

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
plot_anxiety
plot_depression
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
If the full df is needed, I can edit this question.

Comment: In your code, you are creating 3 figures.  The [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537457/how-to-reuse-plot-in-next-jupyter-cell) only works for 1 figure.  The correct approach is to either create one figure with two subplots, or define functions that create the plots and that you can call twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the idea is to have 1 figure with 2 subplots. so that call to `plt.subplots()` should only be done once, and your plots need to reference the output of that.

this is the kind of thing you need to do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)  # only do this 1x 

sns.lineplot(x="time", 
             y="value", 
             hue = "Group",
             ci=90, err_style='bars',
             data=df_long, ax=ax[0])  # use this as 1st plot in `fig`
ax[0].set(xlabel = "Time", ylabel = "Result")
ax[0].set_title('Trajectory of depression during the pandemic', size=20)

sns.lineplot(x="time", 
             y="value", 
             hue = "Group",
             ci=90, err_style='bars',
             data=df_long2, ax=ax[1])  # use this as 2nd plot in `fig`
ax[1].set(xlabel = "Time", ylabel = "Result")
ax[1].set_title('Trajectory of anxiety during the pandemic', size=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you!! However, I need to create the first plot in a chunk and the second plot in another chunk. After that, I'll have to "merge" or "combine" these two different plots in another chunk. is that possible? Thank you again!

Comment: you can reference those plots using `ax[0]` and `ax[1]` anywhere else you need them. hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. I'm almost there to adapt your code to multiple chunks. However, the plots became empty. [image](https://ibb.co/4jGTspn) This issue is probably due to some error in my coding.

Comment: yes put this line `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)` at the top before the Seaborn stuff.